# Could not determine type for: TIMESTAMP, at table: BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ADD_USER_DTM)]

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: TIMESTAMP, at table: BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ADD_USER_DTM)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466)
    at com.hms.api.batch.job.config.StartBatchJobConfigApplication.createSession(StartBatchJobConfigApplication.java:71)
    at com.hms.api.batch.job.config.StartBatchJobConfigApplication.main(StartBatchJobConfigApplication.java:38)
```

The following are my codes. calling createSession() method in Main.
I have two Entity classes.

Database connection is provided in my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
private static void createSession() {

        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();

        SessionFactory factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        SessionFactory fact = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session ss = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tt = session.beginTransaction();

        BatchJobConfig config = new BatchJobConfig();

        BatchJobConfigDetails details = new BatchJobConfigDetails();

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("timestamp  ->  "+timestamp);

        BatchJobConfigDetails batchJobConfigDtl = new BatchJobConfigDetails(300, 3, "JAVA", date, "JAVA", date, "N",
                "Some Key", "Some value", "FT", "KEY DESCRIPTION", "Y");
        try {
            config.setBatchJobConfigDtl(batchJobConfigDtl);
            config.setAddUserCd("gdfdgdfgdgd");
            config.setBatchJobConfigId(505);
            config.setActiveInd("YYYY");
            config.setAddUserDtm(timestamp);
            config.setDeleteInd("N");
            config.setEndDtm(timestamp);
            config.setJobDesc("DESCRIPTION");
            config.setJobNm("JOB NAME");
            config.setJobType("Job Type");
            config.setLastUpdtDtm(timestamp);
            config.setLastUpdtUserCd("someone");
            config.setStatus("COMPLETED");
            config.setStartDtm(timestamp);
            ss.save(config);
            tt.commit();
            System.out.println("config session saved");

        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory!!!!!!!!!!");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fact.close();
            ss.close();
        }

        try {
            details.setAddUserCd("fffffffffffffffffffff");
            details.setAddUserDtm(timestamp);           
            details.setBusinessUpdtInd("dssssssss");
            details.setDeleteInd("NNNNNNNNN");
            details.setKeyDataType("ggggggggggggg");
            details.setKeyDesc("Description.......");
            details.setKeyNm("some key name");
            details.setKeyVal("someval");
            details.setLastUpdtDtm(timestamp);
            details.setLastUpdtUserCd("last user");
            BatchJobConfig batchJobConfig = new BatchJobConfig(1L, "JAVA", date, "C#", date, "N", "MissingCK",
                    "JOB DESCRIPTION", "FT", date, date, "COMPLETED", "Y");
            List<BatchJobConfig> b = null;
            b.add(batchJobConfig);
            details.setBatchJobConfigs(b);
            session.save(details);
            t.commit();
            System.out.println("details session saved");

        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory....");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            factory.close();
            session.close();
        }

    }
```

batchJob.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="BatchJobConfig" table="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG">

        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the BATCH_JOB_CONFIG.
        </meta>

        <id name="batchJobConfigId" type="int" column="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="addUserCd" column="ADD_USER_CD" type="string" />
        <property name="addUserDtm" column="ADD_USER_DTM" type="TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="lastUpdtUserCd" column="LAST_UPDT_USER_CD"
            type="string" />
        <property name="lastUpdtDtm" column="LAST_UPDT_DTM" type="TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="deleteInd" column="DELETE_IND" type="string" />
        <property name="jobNm" column="JOB_NM" type="string" />
        <property name="jobDesc" column="JOB_DESC" type="string" />
        <property name="jobType" column="JOB_TYPE" type="string" />
        <property name="startDtm" column="START_DTM" type="TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="status" column="STATUS" type="string" />
        <property name="endDtm" column="END_DTM" type="TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="activeInd" column="ACTIVE_IND" type="string" />

        <many-to-one name="BatchJobConfigDetails" column="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID"
            class="BatchJobConfigDetails" not-null="true" />

    </class>

    <class name="BatchJobConfigDetails" table="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS">

        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DETAILS.
        </meta>

        <id name="batchJobConfigDtlsId" type="int" column="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="batchJobConfigId" column="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID"
            type="int" />
        <property name="addUserCd" column="ADD_USER_CD" type="string" />
        <property name="addUserDtm" column="ADD_USER_DTM" type="TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="businessUpdtInd" column="BUSINESS_UPDT_IND"
            type="int" />
        <property name="deleteInd" column="DELETE_IND" type="string" />
        <property name="keyDataType" column="KEY_DATA_TYPE" type="string" />
        <property name="keyDesc" column="KEY_DESC" type="string" />
        <property name="keyNm" column="KEY_NM" type="string" />
        <property name="keyVal" column="KEY_VAL" type="string" />
        <property name="lastUpdtDtm" column="LAST_UPDT_DTM" type="TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="lastUpdtUserCd" column="LAST_UPDT_USER_CD" type="string" />

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And created two of this tables in DB2 Database. 
[image]
[image]

My project is spring-boot REST API GET all, GET 1 and PUT operations. Please take a look and let me know where I'm making mistake. Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: Issue resolved. Thanks MS90!! by changing TIMESTAMP(Upper case) to timestamp(lowercase)

Comment: Glad it helped! I wanted to write to comments but instead wrote as an answer. @Titi

Comment: me too. it did not allow me to comment so I wrote as an answer

Comment: Great! Just mark my answer as correct in order to get your question valid and completed. @Titi

Comment: I did marked it as useful. How do I mark as correct?

Comment: There is an empty arrow just below 1 in my answer count. Click on that and it will become green. @Titi

Comment: Got it. Done. Thanks

Comment: Now my exception is Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: BatchJobConfig column: BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:862)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:880) .. can you see the issue?

Comment: OK, make a new question and I will answer there in order not to spam this question. @Titi

Comment: As you can see in your table, you have two identical names BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID names. Change your many-to-one relation name in your hbl.xml file of <many-to-one name="BatchJobConfigDetails" column="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID"
            class="BatchJobConfigDetails" not-null="true" /> to <many-to-one name="CHANGEMEHERE" column="BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID"
            class="BatchJobConfigDetails" not-null="true" />

Comment: I just posted it as new question. By the way I tried changing the name but still got same error message. also I mvn clean install and tried to run Main class as java got same error message.

Comment: One second. @Titi

Comment: Did you update your DB class afterwards? @Titi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all small letters "timestamp" instead of capital ones in your hbm.xml file. Something like:

```
<property name="addUserDtm" column="ADD_USER_DTM" type="timestamp" />
```